# Spring MessageSource resolve / interpolate string multiple times

Tags: java, spring, internationalization

So, I'm fairly certain this is simply due to my own lack of understanding about how various message resolutions/interpolations take place in Spring and Java, what I want:

`InternationalMessages.properties`

```java
BadParsingFormat={{0}} should fall betweeen {1} and {2}
pointTop=The top coordinate
pointLeft=The left coordinate
```

`APIEndPoint.java`

```java
// Standard implementation and wiring of message source
@Autowired
MessageSource messageSource;

public void someMethod(String somethingToParse) {
    String parsed;
        try {
            parsed = SomeKindOfParser.parse(somethingToParse);
        }
        catch(BadParsingFormatException exception) {
            String error = messageSource.getMessage("BadParsingFormat",
                new Object[]{
                        exception.getVariableName(),
                        exception.getLowerBound(),
                        exception.getUpperBound()
                });
            // Do something useful with this error message
        }
}
```

The `exception.getVariableName()` will return either `pointTop` or `pointLeft` in this cheesy example. I want to further resolve/interpolate those down to specific names as well, but I can't quite seem to pull it off. I know I can use another messageSource call and get that bundle value separately, but if I could avoid that, I'd prefer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't think of any other way than what you have already suggested - to make another call to the messageSource:

```
BadParsingFormat={0} should fall betweeen {1} and {2}
pointTop=The top coordinate
pointLeft=The left coordinate
```

With code

```
   String error = messageSource.getMessage("BadParsingFormat",
            new Object[]{
                    messageSource.getMessage(exception.getVariableName(),null, null),
                    exception.getLowerBound(),
                    exception.getUpperBound()
            });
```

Comment: Ah, okay. I was hoping not to have to do this since in my actual application, `APIEndPoint.java` does not actually `@Autowired messageSource`; it's done downstream in a place that I'd have to significantly alter the project design to have it configurably resolve additional times. If there aren't any magical answers in the next day or so, I'll select this one. Thanks!

Comment: In the end, I ended up actually implementing a custom message source, overriding getMessage, and continually resolving the message until it's all shaken out.